# jquery load with chart.js

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I'm loading parts of a page with JQuery Load and want to use chart.js plugin to build a chart as part of a page.  The load html loads fine and the chart will build if you refresh the page, but only sometimes, it never builds the chart on first page load.  Do I need a defer or promise here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you are loading the HTML with the canvas element using jQuery `.load()`, you need to put the chart initialization in the complete callback, like so

```
$("#result").load("canvas.html", function () {
    var data = {
        labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [12, 23, 23, 43, 45, 12, 33]
            }
        ]
    };

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
});
```

where canvas.html is

```
<canvas id="myChart" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
```

---

The canvas element needs have a non-zero render size when the data is loaded, otherwise the chart won't show up.

In most cases, putting the `new Chart...` in the right place (for e.g. in the callback, after a tab is visible, etc.) will be enough. When it's not possible to identify such a point, using a `setTimeout` with enough delay to guarantee that the canvas element is rendered will work.