# How to load page containing Chart.js using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, chart.js

I am trying to load a page containing a chart into a div element on another page using the jQuery load() function. I read [jquery load with chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653943/jquery-load-with-chart-js) which suggests placing chart initialization in the complete callback. However, this will not work for me because my chart labels and datasets are generated by a PHP script as well as several other elements on the page.

Here is the code on my page that contains the chart:

```
<?php 
    /*
    lots of PHP code here that loads the data to display
    final variables generated are $labelsString and $dataSetsString
    $labelsString contains the labels for the chart in the form: "label1","label2","label3" etc.
    $dataSetsString contains the data sets to show in the form:

    {
        label: "Line1",
        fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(1,2,3,4)",
        pointColor: "rgba(1,2,3,4)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(1,2,3,4)",
        data: [1,2,3]
    },
    {
        label: "Line2",
        fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(1,2,3,4)",
        pointColor: "rgba(1,2,3,4)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(1,2,3,4)",
        data: [4,5,6]
    }
    /*
?>



<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    OTHER HTML CONTENT HERE

    <div style="height: 50%;">
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    OTHER HTML CONTENT HERE
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

alert("Got here 1");

        /*
            For config options see: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/
        */

        var lineChartData = {
            labels : [<?php echo $labelsString; ?>],
            datasets : [
                <?php
                    echo $dataSetsString;
                ?>
            ]

        }

alert("Got here 2");

    function loadChart(){

        alert("Got here 2A");

        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

        alert("Got here 2B");

        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true, 
            animation: false, 
            pointDot : false,
            pointDotRadius : 2, 
            pointDotStrokeWidth : 1,
            pointHitDetectionRadius : 10, 
            scaleShowGridLines : false,
            scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.1)",
            scaleBeginAtZero: true,
            bezierCurve : false,
            bezierCurveTension : .2,
            showScale: true,
            scaleShowLabels: true,
            scaleFontFamily: "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif",
            scaleFontSize: 10,
            scaleFontStyle: "normal",
            scaleFontColor: "#666",
            maintainAspectRatio: false
        });

        alert("Got here 2C");
    }

    loadChart();

alert("Got here 3");

</script>
```

The code that calls this page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../chartjs/Chart.js-master/Chart.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="chartArea" class="chartArea"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function loadGo()
{
    $("#chartArea").load("../page.php?foo=bar");
}

loadGo();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page my JS debugging alerts pop up: 1, 2, 2A, 2B. The debugging alerts 2C and 3 do not pop up. When I open the page that contains the chart in a my browser, the chart loads just fine. What is keeping Chart.js from executing properly?

UPDATE: I added another debugging alert box 2B (and changed the old 2B to 2C). 2B executes after the line:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
```

So execution is ending somewhere within the line:

```
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true, 
            animation: false, 
            pointDot : false,
            pointDotRadius : 2, 
            pointDotStrokeWidth : 1,
            pointHitDetectionRadius : 10, 
            scaleShowGridLines : false,
            scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.1)",
            scaleBeginAtZero: true,
            bezierCurve : false,
            bezierCurveTension : .2,
            showScale: true,
            scaleShowLabels: true,
            scaleFontFamily: "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif",
            scaleFontSize: 10,
            scaleFontStyle: "normal",
            scaleFontColor: "#666",
            maintainAspectRatio: false
        });
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: it looks like your php may not be formatting the label correctly, `label: Line1` should probably be `label: "Line1"`

Comment: @diffalot Yes, you are correct. In the actual program it adds the quotes, it looks like I accidentally omitted them when simulating the output. I have edited my question to reflect this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was not with Chart.js but with jQuery restricting pages that "are not on my server". The page that was to be loaded (that contained the chart) used file_get_contents() in PHP to load some external JSON data which was located on another server. I guess my browser was somehow recognizing that data was loaded from an "external" server and did not allow the data to display.